# Failed 'ionic cordova run android' at ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've faced this problem while I'm working on Ionic 2. I could run 'ionic serve'. but running on android device is failed. Could someone help me to get over this. Thank you.

Even I've tried the following steps, still getting the same error.

Remove platform : ionic cordova platform rm android

Re add platform : ionic cordova platform add android

Step 1) ionic cordova prepare android

Step 2) ionic cordova build android

Step 3) ionic cordova run android

> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
>   > Java heap space
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug  option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED  in 44s 47 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 44 up-to-date
>   (node:3775) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>   /Users/name/IonicProjects/prjname/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
>   > Java heap space
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 44s
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/name/IonicProjects/prjname/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:127:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:933:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5) (node:3775)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:3775) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have the **Android API 23** in order for the Android build and run on device.

After installing above things then try your build commands.

If Even this not work then Try to add the Environment variable

> Environment variables > System variables >
>
> add _JAVA_OPTIONS and value = -Xmx512M

For more help please check the same type of issue [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1800).

If this not work for you then try to  remove your `platforms` and `node modules` and install it again.

I think you have created your project on different environment and building another environment.

Hopes this will help you !!

Comment: Hi, I've tried but unfortunately it did not work. I created new project and import my code again. It worked well :) still can't figure out what's wrong with my old prj. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think you have changed your ionic cli version